# Problem for recover and save metaboxes

Tags: plugins, metabox

I create metaboxes but i can´t save data and also no show data insert into field , this is my code

```
    <?php
function reaction_buttons_meta2() 
{
global $post;
echo $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2'];
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'reaction_buttons_off2', $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2']);
$meta=get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['reaction_buttons_off2'], true); 
?>
<input type="text" id="reaction_buttons_off2" name="reaction_buttons_off2" value="<?php echo $meta[reaction_buttons_off2][0]; ?>">
<?php
}
?>
<?php
function reaction_buttons_meta_box2() 
{
add_meta_box('reaction_buttons2','Reaction Buttons','reaction_buttons_meta2','post','side');
add_meta_box('reaction_buttons2','Reaction Buttons','reaction_buttons_meta2','page','side');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2');
?>
```

Comment: Have you read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47828/why-is-add-meta-box-not-working?

Comment: I change the code and contionue no work me

Comment: Please update your question with your changed code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2');
```

Use `'add_meta_boxes'` to add meta boxes. It fires in the `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` file and passes the `$post` object. The `'admin_menu'` action fires much more often.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2' );
```

Your code:

```
function reaction_buttons_meta2()
{
global $post;
echo $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2'];
```

There is nothing in `$_POST` when the the edit page loads. You can test this with `wp_die()`.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2' );

function reaction_buttons_meta_box2() {
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'page', 'side' );
}

function reaction_buttons_meta2() {
    wp_die( '<pre>' . var_export( $_POST, true ) . '</pre>' );
}
```

In the meta box you should see this:

```
array(
)
```

Which means nothing is in $_POST.

Your code:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'reaction_buttons_off2', $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2']);
```

`reaction_buttons_meta_box2()` is not run during post / page save. To add a function on save use this:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save' );

function wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save() {
    wp_die( '<pre>' . var_export( $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2'], true ) . '</pre>' );
}

function reaction_buttons_meta2() {
    printf( '<input type="text" id="%1$s" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" />', 'reaction_buttons_off2', 12 );
}

function reaction_buttons_meta_box2() {
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'page', 'side' );
}
```

Refresh the editor page and `Update` the post. The web page should produce an error with `'12'` in it. The value added in the `printf` line above.

Your code:

```
$meta=get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['reaction_buttons_off2'], true);
```

This code used a variable named `$field` which has never been defined. It should produce a PHP error.

Your code:

```
<input type="text" id="reaction_buttons_off2" name="reaction_buttons_off2" value="<?php echo $meta[reaction_buttons_off2][0]; ?>">
```

This code uses an array key named `reaction_buttons_off2` without quotes. Since `$field` didn't exist in the line above, `$meta` has nothing in it and the corrected code `$meta['reaction_buttons_off2'][0]` should produce a PHP missing index warning.

`reaction_buttons_meta2()` should probably look like this:

```
function reaction_buttons_meta2( $post ) {

    $field_name = 'reaction_buttons_off2';

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_name, true ) )
        $reaction_buttons_off2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_name, true );
    else
        $reaction_buttons_off2 = '';

    printf( '<input type="text" id="%1$s" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" />', $field_name, $reaction_buttons_off2 );
}
```

Saving the data requires some tests:

```
function wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) || current_user_can( 'edit_pages', $post_id ) ) {

        $field_name = '_reaction_buttons_off2';

        if ( isset( $_POST[$field_name] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $_POST[$field_name] );
    }
}
```

The field name, `reaction_buttons_off2` will show up as a custom field and can be edited there as well. If you wish to avoid that add an underscore to the beginning of the field name in both the `wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save()` and in `reaction_buttons_meta2()`.

```
$field_name = '_reaction_buttons_off2';
```

Putting it all together:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save' );

function reaction_buttons_meta_box2() {
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'reaction_buttons2', 'Reaction Buttons', 'reaction_buttons_meta2', 'page', 'side' );
}

function reaction_buttons_meta2( $post ) {

    $field_name = '_reaction_buttons_off2';

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_name, true ) )
        $reaction_buttons_off2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_name, true );
    else
        $reaction_buttons_off2 = '';

    printf( '<input type="text" id="%1$s" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" />', $field_name, $reaction_buttons_off2 );
}

function wpse_47828_reaction_buttons_meta_box2_save( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) || current_user_can( 'edit_pages', $post_id ) ) {

        $field_name = '_reaction_buttons_off2';

        if ( isset( $_POST[$field_name] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $_POST[$field_name] );
    }
}
```

**Note:** You should add some validation to the field during save and it may be a good idea to also add a nonce to check that this form really came from WordPress admin. I don't know if `current_user_can()` will be secure enough.